# Prove that $\bigcup_{U \in \mathfrak{F}} U$ is a subspace of $V.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, $\mathfrak{F}$ a collection of subspaces of $V$ with the following property: If $X,Y \in \mathfrak{F},$ then there exists a $Z \in \mathfrak{F}$ such that $X \cup Y \subset Z.$ Prove that $\bigcup_{U \in \mathfrak{F}} U$ is a subspace of $V.$

I'm having trouble starting this problem, some hints to get me started and nudge me in the right direction (no full answers please) would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Quibble: $\mathfrak{F}$ has to be nonempty, otherwise the union is empty, and $0 \notin \emptyset$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name $U^\prime=\bigcup_{U \in \mathfrak{F}} U$.

For $x,y \in U^\prime$, $x$ and $y$ belong to subspaces $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ with $X,Y$ subspaces of $U^\prime$. By hypothesis, there is a subspace $Z$ such that $X \cup Y \subset Z \subset U^\prime$.

As $Z$ is a subspace, $x+y \in Z \subset U^\prime$.

You can proceed in a similar way to prove that if a vector belongs to $U^\prime$, then it is also the case for its multiplication by a scalar. This allows to conclude as desired that $U^\prime$ is a subspace.

Comment: Interestingly, any union of subspaces would be closed under scalar multiplication, and they'd all contain $0$. It seems the hypothesis that the collection is directed is only needed to handle the binary operation $+$.